# Selection Sort-array sorting

Tags: python

When I run it only the first smallest number gets sorted. Is the problem somewhere in the loops?

```
def selectionSort(A):
    n=len(A)
    print(n)

    mini=0
    for i in range(0,n-2):
        mini=i
        for j in range(i+1,n-1):
            if A[j]<A[mini]:
                mini=j
            if i!=mini:
                temp=A[i]
                A[i]=A[mini]
                A[mini]=temp

    return A
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is somewhere in the loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two issues:

1. Your second `if` should be outside the inner `for` loop.
2. And your outer and inner loop should be iterating till `n-1` and `n` respectively, instead of `n-2` and `n-1`.

---

Hence, your code should be like:

```
def selectionSort(A):
    n=len(A)
    print(n)
    mini=0
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        mini=i
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            if A[j]<A[mini]:
                mini=j
        if i!=mini:
            temp=A[i]
            A[i]=A[mini]
            A[mini]=temp
    return A
```

Output:

```
>>> selectionSort([2, 5, 7, 1, 3, 0, 10, 43, 21, 32])
10
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 21, 32, 43]
```

*Suggestion:* You do not need temp variable in python for swapping values. You can simply do it as:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 3
>>> a, b = b, a
>>> a
3
>>> b
5
```

In your swapping code, it would be as: `A[i], A[mini] = A[mini], A[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem is in the swapping part of your code, it needs to placed after inner for-loop

```
def selectionSort(A):
    n = len(A)
    mini=0
    for i in range(0,n-2):
        mini=i
        for j in range(i+1,n-1):
            if A[j]<A[mini]:
                mini=j
        if i!=mini:
            temp=A[i]
            A[i]=A[mini]
            A[mini]=temp

    return A
```